# logstash - Do not get the values for [log][file][path]

Tags: logstash, elastic-beats

I receive the data from filebeats in logstash but I do not see the value for [log][file][path].
I see othr people get the data in the logstash data, below is what I receive. There is no data from beats for the logpath. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
{
    "_index" : "%{merchant_id}",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "gpPkankB77M3Al5AC9Cs",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "host" : {
        "name" : "53f955bf4e04"
      },
      "message" : "request: \nnull",
      "@version" : "1",
      "@timestamp" : "2021-05-08T09:50:26.090Z",
      "level" : "D",
      "stacktrace" : true,
      "ls_pipe" : "droid_log",
      "agent" : {
        "id" : "dffd6c5f-69e9-416c-b08c-f2229e6d477b",
        "name" : "53f955bf4e04",
        "version" : "7.12.1",
        "type" : "filebeat",
        "ephemeral_id" : "6417dd44-79fd-44a9-8798-5ae188f9fe62",
        "hostname" : "53f955bf4e04"
      },
      "device" : {
        "id" : "1850006639",
        "tid" : "3786",
        "pid" : "3732"
      },
      "tags" : [
        "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
        "_grokparsefailure"
      ],
      "input" : {
        "type" : "log"
      },
      "ecs" : {
        "version" : "1.8.0"
      },
      "logger" : "postiliondriver.parameters.PostilionParamDownloadBase"
    }
  }
```

[image: Logstash Config]

[image: beats]

Comment: Share your filebeat config and your logstash pipeline config, you seem to have some errors in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `drop_fields` processor in your `filebeat.yml` that is dropping the `log` field.

If you drop the field you can't use it in logstash because it does not exists in your message.

Remove the `log` field from the `drop_fields` processor and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will change and test again.

Comment: You saved me many hours, thank you again.